# Started sculpting before I should've, how can I add a mirror modifier again (without messing things up)?

Tags: modeling, mirror, sculpting

I started sculpting before I finished my base mesh. I am wanting to add to the base mesh using the the mirror modifier for symmetry, but when I delete one side, then add the modifier, there is a gap in the middle in sculpt mode. How can I add to the mesh with the mirror modifier, without losing my progress on sculpting?[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, and sorry for the late response. I have tried this multiple times and it still does not work. I suspect this is due to my mirror modifier not being first in the order, as Craig mentioned. I already have a multi-resolution modifier, which is loaded above the mirror. But I cannot seem to move the mirror ahead of it. "Cannot move above a modifier requiring original data" is the error given. Is there any way I can get switch them without losing my sculpting data?

Comment: You could try increasing the merge limit on the mirror modifier, but it's a bit of a workaround..

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to align the central vertices to the object origin:

1. Set the 3D cursor to the origin (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* while in object mode)
2. Switch to edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and select the central verts
3. Set the pivot point to the 3D cursor (<kbd>.</kbd>)
4. Scale them to 0 along the mirror axis. e.g. for mirroring along the X axis, press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure your mirror modifier is first in the stack - otherwise, sometimes your object will split away from the centerline like this.